# Sitefinity 4 redirect to specific page after login

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity-4

Using the Sitefinity login control, I would like to redirect the user to a specific page after they log in. On the control, there is a property of "LoginAction" which is set to "Redirect", however there isn't a property to specify what URL to redirect to.

I am using V 4.1 with SP 1.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, in version 4.1, SP 1 there is a DestinationPageUrl property that redirects the user to the appropriate URL after login. Also if you are adding the LoginControl in the .aspx/.ascx markup, you can also wire up the LoggedIn event of the LoginControl and redirect there as well.

If you still have problems, handle the LoginError event as well - if that event is raised it will short-circuit the LoggedIn event, as well as the DestinationPageUrl property.